# sync data from web service to android device

Tags: android, synchronization

I am creating a meeting in a specific room from a web application and display this meeting into an Android device.

How to sync this data by using a web service without any user interaction in an Android app?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific on the technology you're using and what you want to be displayed on the Android device?

Comment: it is not clear what are you talking about, those type of questions need more details you can't just ask this in general with out organizing your specification and explain it more clearly in an organized way with an organized set of information.

Comment: when  creating a new meeting. i want to automatically refresh android device screen. i am also try to using handler and it was delayed after every 2 minutes but the application will be hanged on device